# TYPO3 v10 How do i get an object's crdate or the tstamp in FrontEnd

Tags: php, typo3, frontend, custom-fields, typo3-10.x

I am using TYPO3 v10 and i have built an extension.

In some parts of the FrontEnd i need to get the crdate or the tstamp. TYPO3 does not have getters and setters to use in order to retrieve them.

Before TYPO3 v10 you could do something like that:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileMount {
               mapping {
                  tableName = sys_filemounts
                  columns {
                     title.mapOnProperty = title
                     path.mapOnProperty = path
                     base.mapOnProperty = isAbsolutePath
                  }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is rather simple. I had to build my own getters and map them. Example the **crdate**:

**Model1.php**

```
/**
* @var \DateTime
*/
protected $creationDate;

public function getCreationDate(): \DateTime
{
    return $this->creationDate;
}
```

**tx_extension_domain_model_model1.php**

```
'crdate' => [
   'exclude' => true,
   'config' => [
       'type' => 'select',
       'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
       'eval' => 'datetime,int',
       'default' => 0,
       'range' => [
           'upper' => mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2038),
       ],
       'behaviour' => [
           'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
       ],
   ],
],
```

**your_extension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php**

```
return [
    \Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Model\Model1::class => [
        'tableName' => 'tx_extension_domain_model_model1',
        'properties' => [
            'creationDate' => [
                'fieldName' => 'crdate',
            ],
            // ...
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now the **crdate** can be retrieved in the FrontEnd

Big Thanks to @Mathias Brodala for pointing me to the right direction.

Best regards