# TYPO3 get the user from cruser_id field

Tags: typo3, extbase, userid

i would like to show the user who created an element. The TCA looks like this:

```
  'ctrl' => [
    'title' => 'Title',
    'label' => 'title',
    'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
    'crdate' => 'crdate',
    'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
```

With getter i can get the tstamp and the crdate. But with the cruser_id this doesn't work. How can i get the user name of the user with the cruser_id?

Comment: i guess it misses the TCA configuration. Try to add it in your TCA. Let me know if this s the right answer to add it as an answer with a bit more information. Btw the variable should not hold an underscore. It should be like this: protected int $cruserId = 0;

Comment: Thes example above is from my TCA.

Comment: which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: I am using TYPO3 11.5.1

Comment: Yes it works. Now i have to get the username from the ID. Can i create a Statement in the Repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example, works on TYPO3 11.5.8 and should work with TYPO3 10 as well.

First you need your getters und setters on your model (**\YourVendor\YourExtension\Domain\Model\YourModel**)

```
/**
 * @var int
 */
protected int $cruserId = 0;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getCruserId(): int
{
    return $this->cruserId;
}

/**
 * @param int $cruserId
 */
public function setCruserId(int $cruserId): void
{
    $this->cruserId = $cruserId;
}
```

Then you need to add the TCA configuration for this specific field. You do not need to add it on `types` or anywhere else. TYPO3 just needs the configuration so it knows what to do with it.

```
'cruser_id' => [
    'config' => [
       'type' => 'input',
       'size' => 10,
       'max' => 255,
   ],
],
```

Last and not least, you need to map it on the right column. So under your `your_extension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php` you need to add your Model and the property:

```
 \YourVendor\YourExtension\Domain\Model\YourModel::class => [
  'columns' => [
        'cruserId' => [
            'mapOnProperty' => 'cruser_id'
        ]
    ]
 ]
```

Here is a reference: [TYPO3 v10 How do i get an object's crdate or the tstamp in FrontEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872545/typo3-v10-how-do-i-get-an-objects-crdate-or-the-tstamp-in-frontend)

---

**Backend User Object**

If you want to get the Backend user information, the steps are the same but some changes need to be made.

**Model**

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Beuser\Domain\Model\BackendUser

/**
 * @var BackendUser|null
 */
protected ?BackendUser $cruserId = null;

 /**
 * @return BackendUser|null
 */
public function getCruserId(): ?BackendUser
{
    return $this->cruserId;
}

/**
 * @param ?BackendUser $cruserId
 */
public function setCruserId(?BackendUser $cruserId): void
{
    $this->cruserId = $cruserId;
}
```

**TCA**

```
'cruser_id' => [
   'config' => [
     'type' => 'select',
     'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
     'foreign_table' => 'be_users',
     'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY username',
   ],
],
```

This will give you the following:

[image]

Hope it helped

Comment: This works. Can i use ```'config' => ['type' => 'passthrough'],``` in the TCA? And how can i get the username of this user? Can i prepare a statement from the be_users table?

Comment: yes it is possible. let me edit the answer