# TYPO3 Version 12 cruser_id

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions, typo3-12.x

I just tested TYPO3 version 12. They decided to remove the `cruser_id` field from the database: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us//Changelog/12.0/Breaking-98024-TCA-option-cruserid-removed.html

I used the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71733930/5903676
So this isn't possible any more.

First i manually added the field to my database (ext_tables.sql):

```
cruser_id       int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

I thought it would be enough because of the getter and setter methods. But that's unfortunately not the case. Does anyone have an idea how to handle this without to rewrite much code? I need the User ID for my articles.

Comment: What do you need exactly? To only read this field? Or do you need to set this field as well? All information about migration is in your linked article: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us//Changelog/12.0/Breaking-98024-TCA-option-cruserid-removed.html#migration

Comment: I need the Information about who created the record (the id of the user). The TYPO3 article isn't useful because they don't show how to use the new functionality.

Comment: I think there is no new functionality, just a link to where to look at. You can easily get the data with SQL queries.

Comment: Do you have an example? In Extbase u have your get and set or should i set the data in the TCA?

Comment: I'd use the QueryBuilder to fetch the data directly from the DB. First you need to take a look how to get this information in the history table.

Comment: If i would know how to get the data i wouldn't ask for help.